# How can find out address of sector with VOLUME_PHYSICAL_OFFSET struct (offset member)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, driver

How can find out address of sector with VOLUME_PHYSICAL_OFFSET struct (offset member)?

Document of [VOLUME_PHYSICAL_OFFSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddvol/ns-ntddvol-_volume_physical_offset)

if not how can find out address sectors of file ?

Comment: Find out address of which sector? By "address" you mean LBA?

Comment: YES ................

Comment: So for a file (given by path?) on a given partition, you want to compute the LBA addresses of the blocks where the file content is stored?

Comment: yes............